# ibm_db_dbi::ProgrammingError when calling a stored procedure with pandas read_sql_query

Tags: python, pandas, stored-procedures, db2

I am attempting to use `pandas.read_sql_query` to call a stored procedure in IBM's db2 and read the results into a dataframe.  However when I do so, I receive the following error:

> ibm_db_dbi::ProgrammingError: The last call to execute did not produce any result set.

I've called the procedure in IBM Data Studio, to confirm that it works as intended, yielding the anticipated approximately 1000 records.  I've also manually queried the table using a `select * from table`, with `read_sql_query` from my script with success.  Therefore I may conclude that the python script is properly configured to work with the database as is the procedure itself.  The struggle seems to be in putting the two together.  My code is below.

```
import ibm_db
import ibm_db_dbi
import pandas as pd

cnxn = ibm_db.connect('DATABASE=mydb;'
                'HOSTNAME=myHost;'
                'PORT=446;'
                'PROTOCOL=TCPIP;'
                'UID=myUser;'
                'PWD=myPassword;', '', '')
conn=ibm_db_dbi.Connection(cnxn)

sql = 'call myschema.getaccountnonrecurringpaging(20230509,0);'
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn)
```

Package details are listed below:

- python=3.10.4
- pandas=1.5.3
- ibm_db=3.1.1
- operating system = Ubuntu 20.04
- db2: v7r4

Comment: How do you return data from your stored procedure?

Comment: Please also specify the version of the SQLAlchemy

Comment: With the above code, the callproc method in dbi will not run.  See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html  (and search for callproc) . You should be able to convert the resulting rows into a dataframe.

Comment: @Lennart-SlavaUkraini Thanks for your response; it's a result set in a cursor.

Comment: @neanderslob  Please raise a new issue at https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/issues  . This was previously raised (but closed) at https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/issues/272  (and I notice that the suggested code change in #272 still works). So it is wise to ask the devs to look again at it. As a workaround in the meantime you can use the callproc method, but the ibm_db_dbi devs should be asked formally to check the issue.

Comment: When I tried your python code against a Db2 11.5 (LUW), it gives a warning before the error: `<stdin>:1: UserWarning: pandas only supports SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection) or database string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connection. Other DBAPI2 objects are not tested. Please consider using SQLAlchemy.`